# Select some rows in python 2d list

Tags: python, list, search

I have a 2d List in python like below:

```
[[0,2,3,4],[0,1,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
```

And I want to get only items that the first item is zero. In this Example the first and second item.
How could I do this?

Comment: You can use list comprehension - `[item for item in a if item[0] == 0]`

Answer (score 4):

```
In [46]: a = [[0,2,3,4],[0,1,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]

In [47]: [i for i in a if i[0] == 0]
Out[47]: [[0, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 3, 4]]
```

OR

```
In [49]: list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 0, a))
Out[49]: [[0, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 3, 4]]
```